# Bootable ubuntu pendrive

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, usb, live-usb

I use both Macs and PCs. I have a pen drive that is in exFAT format and it is 64GB.I am planning on making a bootable live Ubuntu pen drive. I read online that the operating system takes up to 2.5GB space, so if I don't use it to boot and if I plug it in when the system is already running will I be able to use the remainder of the space in Mac or Windows without affecting Ubuntu(The current exFAT format makes it usable in both OSes). If yes- will I be able to access the files that I loaded onto the pen drive through OSX or Windows when I boot up Ubuntu.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We’re sorry, but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Comment: And please search the site at least perfunctorily before you post multiple questions in case some of them are duplicate questions that have already been answered elsewhere at Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the files you want to use on Windows and Mac are on a seperate partition, it shouldn't do anything to Ubuntu

Comment: So, do you suggest I Partition the pendrive?

Comment: And just outta curiosity, what will happen if I copy files into the Ubuntu Partition?

Comment: You can't copy files into the Ubuntu partition. Ubuntu uses an ext4 partition that can't be read by Windows or Mac.

Comment: Yes you should partition your USB.

Comment: I'm just answering question 2 now

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/928395/live-bootable-pen-drive-with-both-windows-and-ubuntu

Comment: I was told to post each question separately ...... so that is the url for the 2nd question bro.