# Live bootable pen drive with both Windows and Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, usb

I use both Macs and PCs. I have a pen drive that is in exFAT format and it is 64GB.I am planning on making a bootable live Ubuntu pen drive.Will I be able to boot into Ubuntu in both of the Windows PC and Mac with the same pen drive?(Please note that I can currently use the pen drive in both OSes as it is in exFAT format, that is if it has anything to do with it)

Comment: Please clarify: Do you want to convert your existing exFAT USB drive into something that also serves as an Ubuntu live disk, or do you intend to create a separate Ubuntu disk? The latter is the easier task, but even it's difficult. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/737779/how-to-create-a-dual-boot-mode-pen-drive-which-can-support-both-uefi-mode-and-le) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/894184/making-a-pen-drive-with-a-image-from-scratch-bootable-both-in-bios-and-uefi-mode) for two discussions. AFAIK, it's not very well-documented, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to. But there are two important factors.

a. You have to make sure that your Windows computer is running Windows 8 or higher. If you are using Windows 7, you can't have a bootable USB that also boots on Mac. (Mac and versions of Windows higher that 8 use [UEFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI), whilst Windows 7 and lower use [BIOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS))

b. Also you have to make sure that both computers can boot from a USB.

Comment: Actually, Windows 7 *can* boot in EFI mode (but doing so on a Mac is *very* hard, and likely to fail on most models), and Windows 8 and later *can* boot in BIOS mode. Mixing and matching BIOS/CSM/legacy-mode and EFI/UEFI-mode booting is possible, but it's a complex minefield, especially when dealing with a bootable USB drive that's to be used on both PCs and Macs.